# Ways of representing $n$ as an ordered sum

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the ordered sum representation of a number $n$, where an ordered sum
is a sum in which the terms that sum up to $n$ are added from greatest-to-least
when moving from left-to-right for the sum. For example, for $n = 4,$ Here are
some ordered sums that represent $4$:
$$4 = 2+2$$
$$4 = 2+1+1$$
$$4 = 2 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0$$
Consider representing $n$ as an ordered sum such that the only numbers that
can be used are $1$ and $2$. I want to show that the number of ways to represent
$n$ as an ordered sum of $1$s and $2$s is equal to the number of ways of
representing $n+2$ as an ordered sum of integers greater than $1$.

To me, this seems like a convenient instance to consider two different cases:
where $n$ is even and where $n$ is odd; note that if $n$ is odd, $n+2$ is odd,
and if $n$ is even, $n+2$ is even.

In the case where $n$ is even, we know that there are $\frac{n}{2}$ $2$s that
add up to $n$. We can represent these $2$'s as either $2$ or $1+1$ in our
ordered sum, and thus the number of ways of representing $n$ as an ordered sum
of $1$s and $2$ comes down to the number of $2$'s that we select to be
represented as $1+1$. Thus, the number of ways to do this is $\frac{n}{2} + 1,$
where that extra $1$ represents the instances where we do not set any of the
$2$'s to be represented as $1+1$.

The case where $n$ is odd is quite similar, since $n-1$ has $\frac{n-1}{2} + 1$
representations. We add that $1$ back to $n-1$ one way to get $n$. Thus, the
number of ways to represent $n$ as an ordered sum of $1$s and $2$s is
$$\left(\frac{n-1}{2} + 1\right)(1) = \frac{n-1}{2} + 1.$$

The question I now have is, how do you even begin to start figuring out how to
count the number of ways of representing $n+2$ as the ordered sum of integers
greater than $1$? Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Your calculation for the ways to represent $n$ with $1$'s and $2$'s is not correct.  It is correct for unordered ways because all you need then is the number of $1$'s.  For ordered ways $1+1+2$ is different from $2+1+1$ and your approach never counts $1+2+1$.  In fact, for $n=4$ there are $5$ ways.  Did you mean unordered sums, or partitions instead of ordered sums or compositions?  The correspondence between types of parts is more characteristic of partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $A(n)$ ordered ways to represent $n$ as a sum of $1$'s and $2$'s, you can either start with a representation of $n-1$ and add a $1$ or a representaton of $n-2$ and add a $2$.  This shows $A(n)=A(n-1)+A(n-2)$, which is the Fibonacci recurrence.  We have $A(0)=A(1)=1$, so $A(n)=F_{n-1}$.  [OEIS A000045](http://oeis.org/A000045), the entry for the Fibonacci numbers, says $F(n)$ is the number of compositions of $n+1$ objects with each part greater than $1$ agreeing with the preceding.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you even begin to start figuring out how to count the number of ways of representing $n$ as the ordered sum of integers greater than $1$?

(Note I substituted $n+2$ for $n$, although it doesn't change the solution.

This is typically called the partition number and is the number of non-negative solutions to the equation 
$$a+ 2b + 3c + 4d + \dots = n.$$

The sequence for the first few $n$ are

$$1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30, 42, 56, 77, 101,\dots$$

More information about the sequence can be found at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000041) (but note that they count $0$ as a coefficient).

Comment: This does not respect the requirement that the parts be greater than $1$.  The value $2$ is partitions of $2$ and they are $2, 1+1$.  The desired answer is $1$.  The OEIS entry for partitions with all parts greater than $1$ is http://oeis.org/A002865, but that is unordered.

Comment: @RossMillikan That seems correct, perhaps I have misunderstood the question (I thought it was $n$ that should be greater than one!). OP, could you clarify?